# How to do keyframe interpolation on matlab?

Tags: transformations, interpolation, animation, matlab

I want to do keyframe interpolation in matlab.

If I understand correctly, it uses splines to approximate the the motion of specific pixel points within the frames(through transforms). Correct me if I'm wrong.

I tried looking but there are no toolboxes or any code for it. Where can I start?

I will be working with video frames. At specific points (say after N frames, N~~100) the first frame encountered is labeled the keyframe.

These frames are the equivalent to what animator artists draw and then animate by getting the computer to approximate frames in between.

I'm interpolating image frames. Literal image frame pixel values.

Imagine this, there are some pixel values I select, then I call those pixel values features and decide to track those pixel values against the frames. Those pixel values must have some sort of trajectory. I want to interpolate pixel values at various points of a trajectory such that the trajectory approximates a smooth motion between the pixel values.

I know the per pixel affine transform matrices between frames, the warps they perform on any single pixel in the image give rise to displacement in the pixel in a frame-time plot and end up being a trajectory. I smooth this thing somehow and have another set of matrices now describing the same thing but smoother.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: You can not be helped until you describe what you interpolate. A keyframe is just the frame where you have no interpolation. But what is in thw keyframe. The underlying mathematical model is important to the interpolation. No model no interpolation. So how do you plan to track the pixels. Vague waving of hands does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do keyframe interpolation on matlab? Any toolboxes present?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3644/how-to-do-keyframe-interpolation-on-matlab-any-toolboxes-present)

Comment: @flawr yes it was me. My previous question got closed as mentioned.

Comment: @joojaa 
I'm interpolating image frames. Literal image frame pixel values. Imagine this, there are some pixel values I select, then I call those pixel values features and decide to track those pixel values against the frames. Those pixel values must have some sort of trajectory. I want to interpolate pixel values at various points of a trajectory such that the trajectory approximates a smooth motion between the pixel values.

Comment: @user6334139 yes but finding the trajectory is another thing and has nothing to do with interpolation. Interpolation only comes into play once you know where the trajectory is going (quite literally you have billions of options on where the pixel went). Look into optical flow tracking. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoMTYnlNNnc

Comment: @joojaa Okay fine I know the per pixel affine transform matrices between frames, the warps they perform on any single pixel in the image give rise to displacement in the pixel in a frame-time plot and end up being a trajectory. I smooth this thing somehow and have another set of matrices now describing the same thing but smoother. So I know where the trajectory is going, now what?

Comment: Yes time to rewrite your question. Your not looking to interpolate pixels but interpolation of matrices. Is it 4 by 4 matrix? Please [EDIT](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/posts/3677/edit) your question

Comment: Matrices are only a representation of things needed to get a trajectory. The end result is still interpolation of the pixel values in the trajectory.

Comment: Not being wiser friend, I've articulated it as it is, thats the problem statement, thats what I couldnt solve, thats why I posted here

Comment: Rather than trying to keep everything abstract, if you have some example data this may make it easier to understand your intention. A series of images or the location data of the points you are working with, perhaps.

Comment: Not keeping anything abstract, I've uploaded my source. It has the problem in it